# Eigen: Default type for MatrixBase in template function?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

Suppose i have some function that can take optional argument of template type.

```
template<typename Scalar = int>
void foo(Scalar *out = NULL)
{
    std::cout << "HI!" << std::endl;
    if(out != NULL)
        *out = 42;
}

float x = 10;
foo(&x);//Call with optional argument
foo();//Call without optional argument
```

Of course compiler cannot deduce type of optional argument from call without optional argument, but we can help it by specifying default template argument

```
template<typename Scalar = int>
```

Suppose now i have real world example with Eigen

```
template</*some template args*/, typename Derived>
void solve(/*some args*/, std::vector<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>> *variablePath)
```

My question is - how to specify some default type for `Derived`?
For example i want to make default type of variablePath to be `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf> *`

Of course I can use some common template argument instead of `Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>` for example

```
template</*some template args*/, typename Matrix = Eigen::MatrixXf>
void solve(/*some args*/, std::vector<Matrix> *variablePath)
```

But i think it's quite dirty

PS Sorry for my English

Comment: `Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::MatrixXf>` would be the base-type of `Eigen::MatrixXf`, but you should never store any `MatrixBase` object by value.

Comment: @chtz so if i use Eigen::MatrixXf as default value for Derived and i will never create variable of type `Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::MatrixXf>` everything will be ok?

Comment: Should be ok, but I don't think you will be able to create any `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>>` of anything (unless you intentionally shoot yourself in the foot somehow). Maybe just template it to `std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols> >` (and more template arguments, if required)

Comment: @chtz Good idea, cumbersome in sense of template arguments but maybe best in sense of readability/safety.
Can you write SO answer? 
And can you explain why it's bad idea to create MatrixBase object? (maybe some link) I just not an expert in Eigen. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you also want to default variablePath to `nullptr`, so just write an overload without the optional argument:

```
template</*some template args*/, typename MatType>
void solve(/*some args*/, std::vector<MatType> *variablePath);

template</*some template args*/>
void solve(/*some args*/) {
  std::vector<MatrixXf> *nullvector = nullptr;
  solve(/*some args*/, nullvector);
}
```